# How can I figure out why my flight was cancelled?

Tags: cancellations

I try to keep the question as general as possible. I received a notification 1h before departure that my flight was cancelled. After a lot of work, I managed to be rebooked on the same flight one week later.

Now, my flight might be cancelled due to stormy weather or because the airline thought it to be unprofitable [e.g. due to new corona regulations]. If it's the latter, I would be quite worried about having rebooked on literally the same connection.

How can I figure out the reason why my flight was cancelled?

Comment: Can you tell us which flight, between which airports at least and which date?

Comment: Ask the airline?

Comment: @Willeke I was trying to keep the question general so it's useful for others, but I'm specifically interested in SK1622 from DUS to CPH today.

Comment: @stephanmg Are they going to truthfully answer?

Comment: @FooBar, that is in the path of Storm Bella, so if they give that as a reason you can believe them.

Comment: @Willeke the first agent wasn't saying anything, and the second just said that the Danish government didn't give clearance for that flight in light of Corona. "It's pretty difficult to get any plane into Scandinavia these days". That just sounds odd seeing there's many international flights landing in Copenhagen today.

Comment: Checking Flightradar or so could be worth or aviationweather.

Comment: `If it's the latter, I would be quite worried about having rebooked on literally the same connection.` I really don't think this is actually a very good predictor of how likely another cancelled flight will be. the situation and rules changes by the day and any flight you pick now has a relatively high likelihood of being cancelled or changed vs normal times.